# Why 1.001298642*10^9 == 1001298642 is returning false?

Tags: matlab, rstudio, wolfram-mathematica, logical-operators

While I was working on Collatz Conjecture, I seen that there was a starting point 1.001298642*10^9 where I were getting 1047 iterations to reach 1. And against these iterations my matlab programming was returning 1001298642 in a string which is 1.001298642*10^9. But when I further work and tested on Matlab

```
>> 1.001298642*10^9 == 1001298642
ans =

  logical

    0
```

which means 1.001298642*10^9 is not equal to 1001298642. But actually both values are same.

I also tested these values on R Studio and same result I got. What is the problem. Am I doing some mistake?

Comment: Can't say for the others, but Javascript is returning true because `1.001298642*10^9 == 1001298642` evaluates to `1.001298642*10^(9 == 1001298642)`, which evaluates to `10` (which is truthy), and `^` is a bitwise operator, not exponentiation

Comment: Even if you use the correct operator (`**` instead of `^`), it will still return false: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004)

Comment: What you guys are saying, I not understand... I check on R Studio and 001298642*10^9 = 1001298642. But 001298642*10^9 == 1001298642 returning false.

Comment: because 10^9 is 3

Comment: `10^9` should be `10 ** 9`. In javascript, `^` is [Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_XOR))

Comment: Matlab is returning false because of floating point representation, see e.g. [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab)

Comment: and `1.001298642*10**9` is `1001298642.0000001` - due to floating point being inprecise

Comment: @adiga Ok, I edit it.

Comment: So, guys what is the solution of this? How I can get out of it?

Comment: Round the value you want to compare to an integer, or compare if they are within a certain error margin. But read the links that were posted in the comments, since they would have told you this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong operator here. `^` is [Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_XOR)). You should be using `**` for [Exponentiation opeartor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation)

Note that, this will return false because `1.001298642 * 10 ** 9` returns  `1001298642.0000001` and not `1001298642` (More on that here: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004))

```js
console.log(1.001298642 * 10 ** 9 == 1001298642)
console.log(1.001298642 * 10 ** 9)
```

---

But, it is interesting that the snippet returns true. `1.001298642*10^9 == 1001298642` enters the `if` block because the expression returns `10` which is a [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value:

```js
console.log(1.001298642*10^9 == 1001298642)
```

In the [Operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table), *Equality operator*(`==`) appears before *Bitwise XOR* (`^`). If you check the the expression in [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/cf6eaa253ff97bd96829c89b11d5987f/774eccf373b71ae2a67a1d84a31a47cdbd9fd388), it is grouped like this:

```js
(1.001298642*10)^(9 == 1001298642)
10.01298642 ^ false
10.01298642 ^ 0 // coerced to zero
```

Comment: Yeah, I removed Javascript code because it is confusing people. My concern is with matlab or RStudio.